# Recursive callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js

Need a little help trying to get this breadcrumb builder working - it's a recursive fetch for parent categories that should return an array of entries. Not quite working and my brain is fried.... currently only returns the last entry.

```
var walk = function(c, done) {
  var results = [];
  Category.findById(c).exec(function(err, cat) {
    if(cat) {
      results.push({ title: cat.title, id: cat.id});
      if(cat.parent) {
        walk(cat.parent, function(err, res) {
          results = results.concat(res);
        });
      }
      return done(null, results);
    }
    done(results);
  });
};

walk(product.categories[0].id, function(err, results) {
//  if (err) console.log (err);
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Note that there is only one parent cat for each and if the cat has no parent then it should end. I had an else just before done(results) but that was not correct either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got it.... Needed to call done from the inner walk call.

```
var walk = function(c, done) {
  var results = [];
  Category.findById(c).exec(function(err, cat) {
    if(cat) {
      results.push({ title: cat.title, id: cat.id});
      if(cat.parent) {
        walk(cat.parent, function(err, res) {
          results = results.concat(res);
          done(null, results);
        });
      } else {
         done(null, results);
      }
    } else {
      done('No cat found'); // Error
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, recursion and callbacks don't mix all that nicely. You're calling `done` after retrieving the first category, but you're not waiting for the other calls to `walk` to complete before calling `done`. You need to wait for them. I'd do something like this (pseudocode):

```
fetch this category
    if no subcategories
        call callback with [{ title: ... }] and return
    pending = number of subcategories
    results = [[{ title: ... }]]
    for each subcategory
        recurse
            pending--
            results[index + 1] = subcategory_results
            if none pending
                call callback with the concatenation of the subarrays of results
```

Comment: he could add a stack counter, so he would just call it once at the lowest level.

Comment: @scones: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're saying. Perhaps you'd like to add your own answer?

Answer (score 0):

how about [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers)? try this.

Good example like this link : [mongo-model example](https://github.com/alexeypetrushin/mongo-model/blob/master/examples/synchronous.js)

and method [synchronize util](https://github.com/alexeypetrushin/mongo-model/blob/master/lib/helper.coffee) written coffee-script